# NextJs Unused Javascript

Tags: next.js

I'm using nextjs on vercel.

Making google lighthouse pagespeed test, on my homepage.

It returns "remove unused javascripts",
And It lists my other staticprops pages' javascript files like;

```
privacy-policy.js
gdpr.js
shopping-cart.js etc.
```

Why It loads other pages, while I am not on those pages?
How can I stop it? They must be loaded at only their own url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NextJS do `prefetch` on default for linked routes.

you can disable it to avoid loading other pages:

```
<Link href="path" prefetch={false} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, with this i'm been able to reduce a lot the unused chunks

Answer (score 0):

When using getStaticProps, the build time happens when the package is built.

If you want to build the page only when you go on it, you should use `getServerSideProps`.